# Turing Machine Blank Symbol After Halting

Tags: turing-machines, alphabet

Given a Turing Machine with input alphabet Σ and tape alphabet Γ. Alphabet Σ does not include the blank symbol, Γ does. Let's represent the blank symbol as _ . Say this Turing Machine, given an input *w*, writes as output *w*_*w*. That is, the output is a repetition of the input with a blank symbol in the middle.

Is the blank symbol then discarded when considering the output? Should we consider the output to be *ww* despite being *w_w* written in the tape? In case the blank symbol is discarded: is it so because it does not belong to Σ or because the blank symbol is always discarded?

Comment: The example you give would be two strings, not one, and only one string is examined at a time. If a blank symbol were allowed into an input string, then you wouldn't be able to determine where the end of a string is.

So in this case, the first w would be received, then the blank space; that signals that this is the end of the string, and it's then checked if it's accepted or rejected. The same thing would happen again with the next w.